# SDL 1.2 reports wrong screen size

Tags: sdl, screen

I have a multi-monitor setup with two displays, both 1920x1200. In games, I can only select resolutions > 1920x1200 (like 2560x1200) which makes games unusable.

Full screen doesn't work either because it switches one display to 800x600 which means I can't reach the close button... I have to kill the game and then, I have to restore my desktop because all windows are moved/resized.

How can I force SDL to use any resolution that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a game you're making with SDL, then use [SDL_SetVideoMode](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_SetVideoMode) to set any resolution you want.  Just pass in values for `width` and `height`.

If this is a game you're trying to play that uses SDL, then you'll have to provide more details, such as what the game is (also, Gaming.SE would be better suited for such a question)

**[EDIT]** If the game uses SDL to get a list of video modes, it calls [SDL_ListModes](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_ListModes). There is currently no way to influence the result of this method with, say, environment variables.

Comment: I was hoping that there is a hidden env variable or something that allows me to force any resolution, no matter what SDL thinks as valid. On a similar train of thought, how does SDL know the available resolutions? Maybe I can add something to this list.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Is this for a game you're making, or a game you're trying to play?

Comment: It's a game that I want to play. I want to know if the game uses a SDL function to figure out the available resolutions and how I can influence this process. If that isn't possible, then I'll have to report a bug :-/

Comment: Without knowing what the game is, it's impossible to know if the game uses an SDL function to figure out available resolutions.  If it does, it probably uses [SDL_ListModes](http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_ListModes), and as far as I know, it's impossible to influence that.

Comment: Where does SDL_ListModes get it's info from?

Comment: @AaronDigulla It seems that, for Windows, SDL_ListModes gets its info from [EnumDisplaySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162611(v=vs.85).aspx). I don't believe there's any way to influence the value, since it uses the `ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS` mode.  If you want to know how it works for operating systems other than Windows, then I suggest you search through the source code.

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time, I've written a patch for SDL 1.2 which allows to force a screen size down its throat: http://blog.pdark.de/2011/12/04/forcing-sdl-to-use-a-certain-window-size/